# Are gravitational waves effected by the curvature of space time (gravitational lensing)?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, curvature, gravitational-waves, gravitational-lensing

I have a basic question I can't seem to find anything on (I keep hearing about how gravitational waves and gravitational lensing were both predicted by Einstein).

We all know about the [gravitational lensing effect as it relates to light](http://news.berkeley.edu/2015/03/05/distant-supernova-split-four-ways-by-gravitational-lens/).  Would a gravitational wave also be subject to having its path "bent" around massive objects/following the curvature of space-time, or would it be able to pass "straight" through?  (Or do we know?)

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: This paper analyses strong gravitational lensing effects on gravitational waves: http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5731

Comment: Roughly speaking, a gravitational wave carries energy and momentum and gravitation acts on everything that has energy and momentum, so a gravitational wave should be deflected similarly to light.

Answer (score 1):

Of course yes, like anything belonging to the universe, but only if the perturbation is not alot smaller than the wavelength, as for any wave meeting an obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

May be not, curvature of space-time itself is gravity (or acceleration). Gravity should not effect gravity wave, just like light (EM wave) would not be effected by electromagnetism.